# How to get missing values from a query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `Forum` and `ForumTag` HABTM relationship. I also have an array of variables named `@tags` . This array contains the names of some ForumTags that I use to filter down the forums. I currently query to get all of the forums that have ALL of the tags in the array @tags.

```
@forums = Forum.joins(:forum_tags).where(:forum_tags => {:name => @tags})
               .group("forums.id").having(['COUNT(*) = ?', @tags.length])
               .includes(:forum_tags).all
```

However, I also want to be able to find the tags that are part of the returned forums, but NOT in the array. Similar to the Stackoverflow  'Related Tags' listing on the right side of the question page.

For example, if I have 4 forums:

```
forum A = tags are ['foo', 'bar']
forum B = tags are ['foo', 'bar', 'blah']
forum C = tags are ['foo', 'bar', 'blee']
forum D = tags are ['blah']

if @tags = ['foo','bar'], then it should return ['blah','blee']
   with the count on blah=1, and count on blee=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
where("forum_tags.name NOT IN (?)", @tags)
```